# Doesn't work iBeacon identifier?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote

I'm using Estimote SDK.

```
PROXIMITY_UUID = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"

// Beacon(iPad Air) 
[[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:PROXIMITY_UUID 
                                    major:2000 
                                    minor:300 
                                    identifier:@"my.test.beacon"];


// Beacon Receiver(Nexus 7 2nd gen) 
beaconManager.startRanging(new Region("regid", PROXIMITY_UUID, null, null));
```

iPad beacon discovered on Nexus 7. Is this correct?

1. Shoes shop 1

   - app name : ShoeperMan
   - identifier : net.xyz.shoe
   - major : 5
   - minor : 10
   - location : Tokyo
2. Shoes shop 2

   - app name : ShoeperMan
   - identifier : net.xyz.shoe
   - major : 10
   - minor : 3
   - locateon : London
3. Thai food restaurant 1

   - app name : Thaiphoon
   - identifier : com.qwer.thai
   - major : 10
   - minor : 3
   - location : Tokyo

Can see products of Shoes shop 2 when run Thaiphoon app in Thai Restaurant 1?(These app use same JSON form)

Comment: It looks like this should work, though the question is not super clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change UUID or major or minor to differentiate between beacons.

Identifier does not play  a role init. Also as most of the beacon manufacturers(Like estimote) do not allow change in UUID you should just use major and minor to identify different beacons.

Comment: @Vipul - where did you get this untrue information that most of the manufacturers (i.e. Estimote) do not allow UUID configuration?

Comment: not right now. You can download Estimote iPhone app and try for your self that it does not allow change in UUID for iBeacons

Comment: @JohnDoe https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/issues/9 in this link read mikey0000's answer.

Comment: @Vipul - That's an outdated thread. The app store app doesn't allow you to do so, but if you read further about their SDK, you'll see it is possible - I have done it, and so many other people too. Please update your answer so people don't get confused.

Comment: @JohnDoe I would be glad if you can direct me to a link or document where I can learn about how to change UUID. As I have been working with Major minor only in my project and it would be helpful.

Comment: @vipulmittal The method writeBeaconProximityUUID:withCompletion is what you're looking for.

http://estimote.github.io/iOS-SDK/Classes/ESTBeacon.html#//api/name/writeBeaconProximityUUID:withCompletion:

Comment: You can use any of their SDK sample codes and include this method once you have a selected ESTBeacon. ESTBeacon is pretty much an extension of CLBeacon, but with additional properties (power, minor, major, uuid, tx rate).

Answer (score 3):

This is Wojtek Borowicz from the Estmiote community team. Just for the record (I cannot post a comment yet): it is possible to change the UUID of your Beacons with Estimote SDK right now. It was not possible before, but the current version of SDK, released couple of weeks ago, does allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. Although shop #1 should have major set to 10 to have similar format to the rest of the shops.